# VM: bridge connection won't work but NAT is okay

Tags: linux, debian, nat, bridge

I messed my server configuration up when trying to set a port scan protection on my Debian on VirtualBox. I did it while being connected via Bridge and now I have no internet connection anymore. When I switch to NAT I have connection but can't access my website with the server ip on Google.

I can't remember which files I modified, what can I do?

Comment: what hypervisor software are you using?

Comment: VirtualBox, I updated the question sorry

Comment: when you state "I can't remember which files I modified", do you mean Debian OS files?

Comment: yes I modified some file to set an exception for my ip when configuring scan protection but I can't figure out which one anymore